# Ownership of real estate in event of fraud: signed APS but deed not transferred due to real estate fraud

Tags: real-estate, property, fraud

In this account I am speaking from the point of view of someone close to me. Suppose a couple years ago I sold my house in Penan to somebody else (both of us are foreigners), whom I'll refer to as B. I agreed to co-host the lawyer B provided for the sale. Malaysia requires that cash payments be transferred through a lawyer, which B did (he has proof he paid). However, after verifying the Agreement of Purchase and Sale (I signed that), the lawyer absconded with the money. The lawyer did not finish transferring the deed, so the deed is still in my name.

Right now neither B nor I can use the house for our purposes. B and I can either settle or take the matter to court. I'm just trying to understand better about what might the court say about who owns the house, which parts of the APS would be relevant to this situation here, and what should be done? I will have the APS in a day or two, I posted because just wanted to get a general idea of what's going on first.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate post of a question asked several times at this site. I'll look for a reference if I can find it.

Comment: Thanks! By the way alternatively have you any idea or know any precedents about what happens to a sale contract if a stakeholder steals the deposit?